# How to calculate accumulated time for a defined frequency?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have rows containing descriptions of services that have been ordered by our customers.

**Table**:
OrderedServices

**Columns**:

- Id (key)
- CustomerId
- ServiceId
- StartDate
- EndDate
- AmountOfTimeOrdered (hours)
- IntervalType (month, week or day)
- Interval (integer)

An example:

```
1;24343;98;2020-01-20;2020-06-05;1.5;day;3
```

The above is read as ”Customer w/ id 24343 has ordered service #98 to be executed 1.5hrs every 3rd day during the period 2020-01-20 up until 2020-06-05”

The first day of execution is always StartDate, so, in the given example, the services is first executed 2020-01-20, followed by 2020-01-23 (20+3), 2020-01-26, 2020-01-29 aso.

Now I want to calculate the total amount of time executed for a given ServiceType for a given time period.

E.g. 2020-01-01 - 2020-01-31 = 4 x 1.5 = 6hrs in total executed time for the above.

What I can’t figure out is how to create a measure, or a calculated table to achieve this.

Does anyone have an idea?

Kind regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the query editor and use the following stepts:

If your column looks like in your example use as first step `Split Column by Delimiter`.
After this just add the following custom column:

[image]